# Web browser control to fill <input> field

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm trying to open a web page in my webbrowser control and change the value of input fields. Works good when I'm doing it like this `webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Email").SetAttribute("value", "example@example.com");`

on a page with defined element Ids, but now I've encountered a page where the html/javascript looks something like this:

```
<input id="${Id}" name="${Id}" type="text" class="text field" value="${Value}" title="${ToolTip}" />
```

So my question is how do I find this specific input field from the C# code?

Comment: I guess you have to find what is the value of `${Id}` in the code `id="${Id}"`, then you will be able to call your *getElementById()* method

Comment: Looks like a javascript template engine needs to run first...

Comment: Are you using webbrowser control in web application?

Comment: I'm using Windows Forms @Golda

Answer (score 3):

Try This

This is a C# coding

```
HtmlElement Elem = AutomationWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById('<your element ID>');
Elem.SetAttribute("value", '<value to assign in input control>');
```

Also you can use variables inside the GetElementById and SetAttribute function

Answer (score 1):

You can find element by class name by using the following function,

```
public static HtmlElement GetHTMLElementByClass(HtmlDocument document, String className)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement element in document.All)
    {
        if (element.GetAttribute("className") == className)
        {
            return element;
        }
    }
}
```